# Transforming Data for Linear Models

Tags: inference, linear-model, data-transformation, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

I am relatively new to statistics and need some help understanding some concepts relating to linear models and their assumptions. My question refers to one assumption, but I am using this as an example for other / all assumptions.

Let's say we have data we want to perform a simple linear model on. We perform the model and check the assumptions. The assumption of homoscedasticity has been violated. I have been taught to try transforming the data and to retest the homoscedasticity. For example, let's say we have transformed the dependent variable (log(y)) and re-tested our model, checked for homoscedasticity and this assumption has now been met.

I assume that when we interpret our results, they have to be interpreted with respect to the transformed data and not the original. Are you able to transform your results back to the original and then interpret your 'original' results? I would like to think you can't, because even though you've run a model and the assumptions haven't been violated as you transformed your dependent variable - this doesn't magically correct the assumption in the original data, which is the data you actually want to learn bout.

I don't think I am understanding exactly why we transform to attempt to correct this assumption of homoscedasticity when it doesn't serve us in understanding our data. Why not just use a different model, like GLMs instead?

Comment: This is poised somewhere between a very general question on regression assumptions and more specific one about heteroscedastic errors. That mix is not out of order but I think it discourages (detailed) answers.

Answer (score 2):

The example is puzzling and in my experience unlikely.

If everything is OK for linear regression, except that errors are heteroscedastic, then logarithmic transformation will mess up that set-up, as transformation necessarily changes the relationship as well as the errors.

The strongest case for transformation of the outcome is that the relationship is at present not linear, but will be straightened by taking logarithms, as when an exponential relationship or power-law (power-function) relationship can be linearised (approximately). But even then there can be a stronger case for generalized linear models with log link.

Here, as elsewhere, I recommend thinking and talking about *ideal conditions*, not assumptions. The most important ideal condition for linear models is that the mean function is indeed linear, so that $y = Xb$ is a good approximation. The behaviour of errors is not so important and over-emphasised in many accounts, even textbooks.

A positive point about transforming the outcome should be that errors too are best thought of on that transformed scale. (If not, then as said, generalized linear models are often preferable.) Usually the only quantities that need or benefit from  back-transformation are the fitted or predicted values, and confidence limits around them, and that is simple: natural logarithms are inverted by exponentiation, and so forth.

Comment: The distribution of errors would be important for prediction intervals, although they do not need to be normal in order to be estimated. This is not a point particularly in favor of using a log transform however.

Comment: @Galen Naturally I agree.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for your answer, it has given me a better understanding and I definitely need to do more research into this topic. My course doesn't seem to be going into this much detail, which is very unfortunate. Hopefully, this changes as we progress.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

> I have been taught to try transforming the data and to retest the
> homoscedasticity.

I don't doubt you have been taught this. But I think it is a mistake.

> Why not just use a different model, like GLM's instead.

Well, you are right to use a different model, but a) GLM is the acronym for both general and generalized linear model. Which do you mean?  and b) I think what you really want is either robust regression or quantile regression, or maybe a tree or some version of a tree. There are robust versions of generalized linear models, but you may just need a robust version of regular OLS regression (which is a general linear model).

But "different model" is the way to go. Don't make the data fit the model, choose a model that fits the data.

(Yeah the terminology is very confusing; I didn't make it up).

Comment: On occasion I see "multilinear regression" instead of "multiple linear regression". Throws me every time when I am suddenly hoping to see tensors products but suddenly feel disappointed that the OP didn't know what a multilinear map is.

Comment: @Galen Yeah. Also "multivariate regression" where they mean "multiple".

Comment: @PeterFlom thank you for your answer! I meant generalized linear models. I will do some research into the other regressions you've mentioned. Thank you.